# get details of person from address book swift macOS

Tags: swift, macos, addressbook

good evening,

today i start programming of my first macOS program in swift.
unfortunately i find no tutorial which can solve my issue.

i have a view controller with an "abpeoplepickerview".
this shows me successfully my mac address book contacts.

now i would like to select an person an get all details of this person which i would like to fill into textfields.

but i don't know how.
can everybody helps me (please step by step)

thank you very much :)

Comment: The [Contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts) is the same in iOS and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You get selected contacts with `ABPeoplePickerView.selectedRecords`.

Then you iterate through it with `foreach`. You may want to check if the record is `ABPerson` before casting the record to it. After that you read the properties from `ABPerson` and display them in the text fields.